# What's the name of the typeface in the YumBug logo?

Tags: font-identification, logo

[image]

Hi everyone, please help me: which font is used in this logo? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It could be  probably [Berlin Sans Demi](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/berlin-sans/berlinsans-demi/)

[image]